# Incorrect behavior with dplyr's left_join?

Tags: r, merge, left-join, dplyr

Surely this is not intended?  Is this something that happens in other parts of `dplyr`'s functionality and should I be concerned?  I love the performance and hate `data.table` syntax.  Is there an alternative to `dplyr` and `data.table` that is currently safe to use and still high performance?

```
A <- structure(list(ORDER = c(30305720L, 30334659L, 30379936L, 
                     30406397L, 30407697L, 30431950L), 
                    COST = c("0", "", "11430.52", "20196.279999999999", "0", "10445.99")), 
               .Names = c("ORDER", "COST"), 
               row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
               class = "data.frame")

B <- structure(list(ORDER = c(30334659, 30379936, 30406397, 30407697, 30431950), 
                    AREA = c(0, 2339, 2162, 23040, 475466)), 
               .Names = c("ORDER", "AREA"), 
               row.names = c(4L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 15L), 
               class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Garbage results:

```
left_join(A, B)
  ORDER    COST                 AREA
1 30305720                  0   NA
2 30334659                      NA
3 30379936           11430.52   NA
4 30406397 20196.279999999999   NA
5 30407697                  0   NA
6 30431950           10445.99   NA
```

Effective results:

```
merge(A, B, all.x=T, all.y=F)
     ORDER               COST   AREA
1 30305720                  0     NA
2 30334659                         0
3 30379936           11430.52   2339
4 30406397 20196.279999999999   2162
5 30407697                  0  23040
6 30431950           10445.99 475466
```

Comment: I'm using R version 3.1.

Comment: Note this appears to be repoerted here https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/601

Comment: Note that the `data.table` syntax `setDT(A);setDT(B);setkey(A,ORDER);setkey(B,ORDER);A[B]` works to provide the "effective results". `data.table` makes keys/grouping equal within machine tolerance.

Comment: If the merge *did* fail and gave you the wrong results and you presented them where ever, it would be *your* fault.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I posted something similar the other day. I think what you need to do is to have ORDER as numeric (or possibly the other way around). A has ORDER has integer. But B has ORDER as numeric. At the moment, `dplyr` asks you to have group-by variables in the same class. I received a comment from an SO user saying that this is something Hadley and his team has been working on now. This issue will be fixed in the future.

```
A$ORDER <- as.numeric(A$ORDER)
left_join(A,B, by = "ORDER")

     ORDER               COST   AREA
1 30305720                  0     NA
2 30334659                         0
3 30379936           11430.52   2339
4 30406397 20196.279999999999   2162
5 30407697                  0  23040
6 30431950           10445.99 475466
```

**UPDATE**
After exchanging comments with thelatemail, I decided to add more observations here.

**CASE 1: Treat ORDER as numeric**

```
A$ORDER <- as.numeric(A$ORDER)

> left_join(A,B, by = "ORDER")
     ORDER               COST   AREA
1 30305720                  0     NA
2 30334659                         0
3 30379936           11430.52   2339
4 30406397 20196.279999999999   2162
5 30407697                  0  23040
6 30431950           10445.99 475466

> left_join(B,A, by = "ORDER")
Source: local data frame [5 x 3]

     ORDER   AREA               COST
1 30334659      0                   
2 30379936   2339           11430.52
3 30406397   2162 20196.279999999999
4 30407697  23040                  0
5 30431950 475466           10445.99
```

If you have ORDER as integer in both A and B, that works too.

**CASE 2: Treat ORDER as integer and numeric**

```
> left_join(A,B, by = "ORDER")
     ORDER               COST AREA
1 30305720                  0   NA
2 30334659                      NA
3 30379936           11430.52   NA
4 30406397 20196.279999999999   NA
5 30407697                  0   NA
6 30431950           10445.99   NA

> left_join(B,A, by = "ORDER")
Source: local data frame [5 x 3]

     ORDER   AREA               COST
1 30334659      0                   
2 30379936   2339           11430.52
3 30406397   2162 20196.279999999999
4 30407697  23040                  0
5 30431950 475466           10445.99
```

As suggested by thelatemail, integer/numeric combination does not work. But numeric/integer combination works.

Given these observations, it is safe to be consistent in group-by variable at the moment. Alternatively, `merge()` is the way to go. It can handle integer and numeric.

```
> merge(A,B, by = "ORDER", all = TRUE)
     ORDER               COST   AREA
1 30305720                  0     NA
2 30334659                         0
3 30379936           11430.52   2339
4 30406397 20196.279999999999   2162
5 30407697                  0  23040
6 30431950           10445.99 475466 

> merge(B,A, by = "ORDER", all = TRUE)
     ORDER   AREA               COST
1 30305720     NA                  0
2 30334659      0                   
3 30379936   2339           11430.52
4 30406397   2162 20196.279999999999
5 30407697  23040                  0
6 30431950 475466           10445.99
```

**UPDATE2 (as of the 8th of November, 2014)**

I am using a dev version of `dplyr`(dplyr_0.3.0.9000), which you can download from Github.
The issue above is now solved.

```
left_join(A,B, by = "ORDER")
#     ORDER               COST   AREA
#1 30305720                  0     NA
#2 30334659                         0
#3 30379936           11430.52   2339
#4 30406397 20196.279999999999   2162
#5 30407697                  0  23040
#6 30431950           10445.99 475466
```

Comment: +1 - beaten to the punch. I'm still baffled as to why `left_join(B, A)` seems to work ok though.

Comment: @thelatemail That is an interesting observation. If that is the case, this is a real bug then?

Comment: At a quick glance, I'd say it is. It wouldn't be consistent to me for an integer/numeric join to fail but a numeric/integer join to succeed.

Comment: @thelatemail I'll update my answer with all observations. This is something useful for the community.

Answer (score 1):

From the [dplyr documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.7/topics/join):

> **`left_join()`**
>
> returns all rows from `x`, and all columns from `x` and `y`. Rows in `x` with no match in `y` will have `NA` values in the new columns. If there are multiple matches between `x` and `y`, all combinations of the matches are returned.
>
> **`semi_join()`**
>
> returns all rows from `x` where there are matching values in `y`, keeping just columns from `x`.
>
> A semi join differs from an inner join because an inner join will return one row of `x` for each matching row of `y`, where a semi join will never duplicate rows of `x`.

Is `semi_join()` a valuable option for you?