# Are integer vectors numeric vectors in R?

Tags: r, vector

I have an integer vector that I expected I could treat as a numeric vector:

```
> class(pf$age)
[1] "integer"
> is.numeric(pf$age)
[1] TRUE
```

However, when I try to use it to calculate a correlation, I get an error:

```
> cor.test(x = "age", y = "friend_count", data = pf)
Error in cor.test.default(x = "age", y = "friend_count", data = pf) : 
  'x' must be a numeric vector
```

None of my best guesses at alternate syntax work either: http://pastie.org/9595290

What's going on?

Edit:

The following syntax works:

```
> x = pf$age
> y = pf$friend_count
> cor.test(x, y, data = pf, method="pearson", alternative="greater")
```

However, I don't understand why I can't specify x and y in the function (as you can with other R functions like `ggplot`).  What is the difference between `ggplot` and `cor.test`?

Comment: @Gregor, it doesn't.  I included that example in my pastie of alternate syntax.

Comment: Oops, my mistake I had `age` and `friend_count` defined in my global environment, and my `data` argument was silently ignored.

Comment: @Gregor no worries :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't refer to variables using character strings like that in a function call. You want to pass to the `x` and `y` arguments numeric vectors. You passed length 1 character vectors:

```
> is.numeric("age")
[1] FALSE
> is.character("age")
[1] TRUE
```

Hence you were asking `cor.test()` to compute the correlation between the strings `"age"` and `"friend_count"`.

You also mixed up the `formula` method of `cor.test()` with the `default` one. You supply a formula and a `data` object **or** you supply arguments `x` and `y`. You can't mix and match.

Two solutions are:

1. `with(pdf, cor.test(x = age, y = friend_count))`
2. `cor.test( ~ age + friend_count, data = pf)`

The first uses the default method, but we allow ourselves to refer to the variables in `pf` directly by using `with()`. The second uses the formula method.

As to your question in the title; yes, integer vectors are considered numeric in R:

```
> int <- c(1L, 2L)
> is.integer(int)
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(int)
[1] TRUE
```

*Do note @Joshua Ulrich's point in the comment below*. Technically integers are slightly different to numerics in R as Joshua shows. However this difference need not concern users most of the time as R can convert/use these as needed. It does matter in some places, such as `.C()` calls for example.

Comment: I know Gavin knows this, but as a warning to others: I'd be careful saying that "integer vectors are considered numeric in R". `is.numeric(integer())` is `TRUE`, but `identical(numeric(), integer())` is `FALSE`. This is because `is.numeric` is documented to return `TRUE` for integer vectors.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich +1 (I was glossing over that subtlety as I suspected that wasn't really the OP's question, but you are right to clarify my sloppiness :-)

Comment: here is a somewhat exotic bug which exploits the fact that integers are not numeric: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859502/incorrect-behavior-with-dplyrs-left-join

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'get' with strings to get data:

```
age = pf$age
friend_count = pf$friend_count
```

or:

```
attach(pf)
```

then following should work:

```
cor.test(x = get("age"), y = get("friend_count"))
```