# Unexpected behavior with merge and dplyr's left_join

Tags: r, merge, left-join

I have noticed an unexpected behavior with the `merge` function in base `R` as well as the `left_join` function of `dplyr`. 
Below is a minimal example of the data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="serialno   var1 pos_var1
1       C001        NA       NA
2       C002        NA       NA
3       C003 0.1790000        1
4       C004        NA       NA
5       C007 0.0645000        1
6       C010 0.3895000        1
11      C016 0.2805000        1
12      C017 0.7805001        1", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df1
serialno      var1  pos_var1
1      C001        NA       NA
2      C002        NA       NA
3      C003 0.1790000        1
4      C004        NA       NA
5      C007 0.0645000        1
6      C010 0.3895000        1
11     C016 0.2805000        1
12     C017 0.7805001        1

df2 <- read.table(text="serialno   var1  var2
1      C003 0.1790 1.1305
2      C007 0.0645 0.2985
3      C010 0.3895 0.1705
4      C016 0.1740 0.3980
5      C017 0.4840 0.3375", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df2
serialno   var1     var2
1     C003 0.1790 1.1305
2     C007 0.0645 0.2985
3     C010 0.3895 0.1705
4     C016 0.1740 0.3980
5     C017 0.4840 0.3375

left_join(df1,df2)
Joining by: c("serialno", "var1")
serialno      var1 pos_var1  var2
1     C001        NA       NA     NA
2     C002        NA       NA     NA
3     C003 0.1790000        1 1.1305
4     C004        NA       NA     NA
5     C007 0.0645000        1 0.2985
6     C010 0.3895000        1 0.1705
7     C016 0.2805000        1     NA
8     C017 0.7805001        1     NA
```

I expected the last two values of `var2` to be `0.3980` and `0.3375` and not `NAs`.
I get similar result with `merge`:

```
merge(df1,df2, all.x=T)
serialno      var1 pos_var1  var2
1     C001        NA       NA     NA
2     C002        NA       NA     NA
3     C003 0.1790000        1 1.1305
4     C004        NA       NA     NA
5     C007 0.0645000        1 0.2985
6     C010 0.3895000       NA 0.1705
7     C016 0.2805000        1     NA
8     C017 0.7805001        1     NA
```

However when I omit the variable `var1` in the two data frames(note the `var1` variables in the two data frames are the same except for decimal places) the problem is fixed:

```
left_join(df1[,-2],df2[,-2])
Joining by: "serialno"
serialno pos_var1  var2
1     C001       NA     NA
2     C002       NA     NA
3     C003        1 1.1305
4     C004       NA     NA
5     C007        1 0.2985
6     C010       NA 0.1705
7     C016        1 0.3980
8     C017        1 0.3375
```

So it seems that the issue is caused by the conflicting `var1` but I expected the `var1` in the data frame specified first in the join to override the one in the second data frame without any side effects.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to overcome this issue or comments as to whether this is a problem worth looking at fixing?
I have looked around for related posts which address similar issues but they don't address my specific problem. In particular, the issue with those posts is due to type differences e.g. if one of the variables in the first data frame is a character and the corresponding variable in the other data frame is a factor or if one is an integer and the other is numeric e.g. 
[Incorrect behavior with dplyr's left_join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859502/incorrect-behavior-with-dplyrs-left-join)

Comment: This behaviour is both expected and consistent per the documentation. I have no idea what's the questions is about. The join is performed on the mutual columns names in both data sets. If there is no join, you'll receive an `NA`, what else would you expect to get?

Comment: I expected the result as the one generated by `left_join(df1[,-2],df2[,-2])` but in addition the column in `var1` of the first data frame (after overriding the `var1` in the second data frame). But I guess I need to understand more the logic with merging

Comment: When you performing a left join by **two** columns, the merge will try to match **both** per each row in `df1`, so if one of the columns doesn't match, this will return an `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In follow up to the above useful comments*

if you do not mention the column names with which you want to `left_join()` or `merge()` the data frames, then all the columns with the common column names will be considered.

You are getting `NA` in the last two places of var2 column because both the functions are merging the data frames using `serialno` and `var1` columns *(common between df1 and df2)*, and all the values of column `var1` in df1 and df2 do not match.

So if you are willing to merge two data frames it is always better to mention the column names with which you need to merge or join

In your case

```
# using merge()
merge(df1, df2, by = c('serialno'), all.x=T)

#> merge(df1,df2, by = c('serialno'), all.x=T)
#serialno    var1.x pos_var1 var1.y   var2
#1     C001        NA       NA     NA     NA
#2     C002        NA       NA     NA     NA
#3     C003 0.1790000        1 0.1790 1.1305
#4     C004        NA       NA     NA     NA
#5     C007 0.0645000        1 0.0645 0.2985
#6     C010 0.3895000        1 0.3895 0.1705
#7     C016 0.2805000        1 0.1740 0.3980
#8     C017 0.7805001        1 0.4840 0.3375

# using left_join()
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("serialno"))

#> left_join(df1, df2, by = c("serialno"))
#serialno    var1.x pos_var1 var1.y   var2
#1     C001        NA       NA     NA     NA
#2     C002        NA       NA     NA     NA
#3     C003 0.1790000        1 0.1790 1.1305
#4     C004        NA       NA     NA     NA
#5     C007 0.0645000        1 0.0645 0.2985
#6     C010 0.3895000        1 0.3895 0.1705
#7     C016 0.2805000        1 0.1740 0.3980
#8     C017 0.7805001        1 0.4840 0.3375
```

Comment: Since I need one `var1` with `var1.x` taking precedence then I would need to go further and drop `var1.y` (or any other such variables) and rename `var1.x` to `var1` if needed